# Single-column table at the top of the first column of a double-column Latex document

Tags: tables, two-column

I am writing my paper using Bioinformatics Latex template. I want to insert a single-column table at the **top of the first column** of this double-column document, but a huge blank is shown in the second column. How can I fix this bug?

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\processtable{Performance of different basic models in cross-validation scenario. The best results for each metric in each sub-ontology are highlighted in bold font. ``NBR" refers to Neighbors.\label{tab:basicmodel_cv}} {
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}clccc}
\toprule
Sub-ontology         & Component              & $F_{\max}$ & AUROC  & AUPR   \\
\midrule
\multirow{12}{*}{PA} & STRING        & 0.4174          & 0.6073          & 0.2697          \\
                 & GeneMANIA     & 0.3506          & 0.7017          & 0.2604          \\
                 & BioGRID       & 0.3441          & 0.5802          & 0.2677          \\
                 & GO BP         & 0.3777          & 0.6560          & 0.2926          \\
                 & GO CC         & 0.3643          & 0.6396          & 0.2916          \\
                 & GO MF         & 0.3343          & 0.5974          & 0.2403          \\
                 & InterPro      & 0.3588          & 0.5864          & 0.2699          \\
                 & Trigrams      & 0.2941          & 0.5087          & 0.1564          \\
                 & NBR-STRING    & \textbf{0.4213} & \textbf{0.7734} & \textbf{0.3635} \\
                 & NBR-GeneMANIA & 0.4110          & 0.7067          & 0.3550          \\
                 & NBR-BioGRID   & 0.3529          & 0.6273          & 0.2822          \\
                 & Na\"ive       & 0.3517          & 0.5000          & 0.2610          \\
\midrule
\multirow{12}{*}{CC} & STRING        & 0.5143          & 0.6055          & 0.4125          \\
                 & GeneMANIA     & 0.4847          & 0.6313          & 0.4761          \\
                 & BioGRID       & 0.5036          & 0.5791          & 0.4528          \\
                 & GO BP         & 0.5080          & 0.5929          & 0.4357          \\
                 & GO CC         & 0.4968          & 0.5782          & 0.4357          \\
                 & GO MF         & 0.4678          & 0.5599          & 0.4161          \\
                 & InterPro      & 0.5074          & 0.5661          & 0.4666          \\
                 & Trigrams      & 0.4698          & 0.5154          & 0.3829          \\
                 & NBR-STRING    & \textbf{0.5426} & \textbf{0.6809} & 0.4909          \\
                 & NBR-GeneMANIA & 0.5393          & 0.6435          & 0.4821          \\
                 & NBR-BioGRID   & 0.4849          & 0.5800          & 0.4440          \\
                 & Na\"ive       & 0.4849          & 0.5000          & \textbf{0.4939} \\
\botrule
\end{tabular*}}{}
\end{table}
```

Huge blank on the right side 
[image: Huge blank on the right side]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please turn your code framgent into a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces your problem by adding the documentclass and the relevant packages.

Comment: If you use \begin{table*} \end{table*} (pay attention to the star) and use \textwidth instead of \columnwidth, the tabular will stretch over both column, and you will get rid of the with space.